Search is not showing any results
I have Sharepoint 2019. After configuring search services, I created a page with 2 webparts - search box and search results.
Published it, set website to "access for anyone". If I do search inside server farm it is showing results, but if I do search using this page outside servers farm in my local network PC it is showing error :

Nothing here to matches your search

This happened if I add any filter to query or Result Sources
How can fix this issue?
Update: if I am using URL https://wwww.mysite.com it is working but if without www it is not working .
